# How to get touch position in camera in android

Tags: android, video, image-processing, touch, android-camera

I am a beginner in both Java and Android development. I followed the Android "Hello word" and the video recording tutorials online. Now I get a sense how to create an app. Now I am trying to get a touch position (x,y coordinate) during my video recording and I want to return the touch position for later image processing. How should I do this? Where should I put my touch position code? If anyone could help me, I would really appreciate it.